# How to remove duplicate values in two columns and fetch only specific value in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to write a query in which i have to add conditions on two columns , conditions is like, the first column aquire_nation and second column in target_nation. I have to find all records those are having either germany in aquire_nation or germany in target_naton, But records those are having germany in both columns should not be fetched.
Here is my table

[image]

As it is showing in image only last four records should be fetched. first two rows should not fetch.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
Select * from yourtable 
Where 'germany' in (aquire_nation,target_nation)
and NOT(aquire_nation = 'germany' and target_nation = 'germany')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple logic in the `where` clause:

```
where 'germany' in (acquire_nation, target_nation) and
      acquire_nation <> target_nation
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this.

```
Select * from yourtable 
where acquire_nation <> target_nation
```